# allegro - How to draw limited part of display

Tags: c, allegro

I'm coding a game like agar.io and I want to create a world like 5000x5000 but for example player can see only 900x600 part.

Namely player must have a scope. My background is not a bitmap, I'm basicaly make backbuffer black, draw primitives on it and flip it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use google, try somewhere. If you find a more specific problem (you will), come back and ask this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like [transforms](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/transformations.html) could help you out here.

Basically, you have a 900x600 display (`al_create_display(900, 600)`), but let your objects have positions anywhere in the 5000x5000 space.

When your player moves, you shift the camera transformation along with them. Your draw loop might look like this:

```
  al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

  ALLEGRO_TRANSFORM trans;
  al_identity_transform(&trans);
  al_translate_transform(&trans, -player_x, -player_y);
  al_use_transform(&trans);

  // draw the player
  al_draw_filled_circle(player_x + SCREEN_W / 2, player_y + SCREEN_H / 2,
                        32, al_map_rgb(255,0,0));

  // draw all other entities
  // ....

  al_flip_display();
```

Note that the camera is shifted by `-player_x,-player_y`. If the player is at
(1000, 1000), an object at (1500, 1500) should be drawn at
(1500-1000,1500-1000), or (500,500) *relative* to the player. An object at (500,
500) would be drawn at (500-1000,500-1000) or (-500,-500); it will be
off-screen.

We don't actually have to perform this subtracion for every object though. You just draw every object at its *absolute* position, and the transform will translate it to a position *relative* to the player (the player's 'local' space).

Note also that we add half the screen size so the player is centered.

There are a number of ways to approach this, but the above should give you a
good start. As a bonus, using transforms makes it easy to add things like zoom
and rotation.